# Android: use a global object instead of creating new ones

Tags: java, android, global

I have a class A in my Android app where I have some methods.
Those methods are public and used in other classes (B, C, D, E, F ...).

Is there a possibility to create only once the object from the class A and then use it in the other classes or i have to create new object in each classe.

Actually I have to do in each classe (B, C, D, E, F ...)

```
A a = new A();
a.xxxx;
```

It will be great if I can create only once the object a and then call it in my other classes.

thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class A{
    static A a;
    static{
          a = new A();
    }
}
```

In every other class use

```
A.a to get the object and call respective methods as
A.a.xxxx()
```

Comment: I need now the context in my class A to instantiate te object inside and this is not an activity...

Comment: @Ana I think you should see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339941/android-how-to-use-getapplication-and-getapplicationcontext-from-non-activity

Answer (score 6):

Use a singleton pattern. It allows you to use the same instance across classes:

http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-singleton-design-pattern

Answer (score 2):

Use static methods's analogy to do this.

For example:

```
public class Helper{
    public static void doSomething(){
        //do something here
    }
}
```

Now in your other classes, use the above method as below:

```
Helper.doSomething();
```

Or [Singleton](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=46) pattern would be an alternate too.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of that why don't you make those methods static or consider single instance pattern if there are no states involved..

[how to use static methods](http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/howtoaccessstaticmethod.shtml) and [singleton pattern](http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/SingletonPattern.shtml)

Comment: Thank you @sandy, can you please give me some more precisions about this?

Comment: static methods are generally discouraged as a bad idea for most purposes, as they make your design harder to change later.  The singleton pattern is probably a better solution here.

Comment: @Jules.. If there are no states involved why not..? Easy to access.. and simple code...

Comment: @Jules.. read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/752758/is-using-a-lot-of-static-methods-a-bad-thing

Comment: Thank you @sandy, I will try this. One more question, what if I need the context in my A class and this is not an activity?

Comment: If consider making it a Single Instance.. then You can take Context as its argument in **getInstane()** method.. or if you go with statics i think you need to add Context argument to all methods which needs it..

Answer (score 1):

I see the following 3 possibilities:

**1.** If these are just "normal" helper methods you may also just do

> **class B extends A**

and inherit the methods of A into B,C,D,E,....

**2.** However if you need internal memory of class A which is global to all other classes or their instances of B,C,D then may use the static pattern like

```
class A{

static int myGlobalIntVariable; //which is accessible from everywhere 
static void myHelperMethod1() {

}
```

**or 3.** Also you may use singleton as mentioned above which creates an instance that you use everywhere.

Just as a remark, you may use singleton or static pattern depending what you prefer when accessing the methods.

For static patter you have to call them like:

```
A.myHelperMethod();
```

and for singleton you have to do:

```
A.getSingleton().myHelperMethod1();  or A.singleton.myHelperMethod1()
```

if you have defined a variable called `singleton` within Class A

Which one to use really depends on your needs and taste :-)