# How to get a Global variable from one class to another?

Tags: android, constructor, android-context

Hi have one database and I've created a Database class that has a private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper to help me manage my database.

This database is access from four different activities.

Now What I need is? I have a GlobalClass like this:

```
public class Question extends Application{
     private String check;
     public String getCheck() {
         return check;
     }
     public void setCheck(String check) {
         this.check = check;
     }
}
```

In FirstScreen Activity I have a value for `String check`. If I get in other Activity Class its fine, no problem.

If I get in `DBHelper` I can't. I have tried like this:

```
final Question quiz = (Question) getApplicationContext();

final String check  = quiz.getCheck();
```

it shows error in `getApplicationContext()`. How can I get that value in DBHelper class

Please let me know what is wrong with the syntax.

Comment: your dbhelper is not extending activity so no context cannot be used.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339941/android-how-to-use-getapplication-and-getapplicationcontext-from-non-activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in DBHelper you will not have ApplicationContext till you don't pass it.

instead of this do one thing make a static String in your Application class and use it.
as Application class is a single ton instance which remains in memory till the end so it will not use much memory.

```
public class Question extends Application{
    public static String check = "";
}
```

Retrieval of the value

```
public class DBHelper {

    public method() {
        String check = Question.check;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a `Context` in your `DBHelper` class.

You either need to pass in a `Context` when you instantiate the `DBHelper` class (preferred but not always practical) or get the `Context` from your `Question` by doing something like the following.

```
((Question)Question.getAppContext())
```

The `Context` is then returned via a `getAppContext()` method in `Question`.

Comment: @DiscoS2 we will not have `getAppContext()` method in DBHelper as it is not an Activity class.